# When I am fetching the values from property file using ResourceBundle,I get an exception

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

```
ResourceBundle bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("abc");
ipAddress = bundle.getString("ipAddress");
```

I get the following exception:

```
java.util.MissingResourceException: Can't find resource for bundle 
java.util.PropertyResourceBundle, key ipAddress
```

Comment: Yeah, because the key `ipAddress` is not in the resource bundle `abc`. Where is the problem? You should further desribe what you expect.

Comment: Also, a ResourceBundle is meant for internationalization. If you just want to read properties from a properties fril, use java.util.Properties.

Answer (score 1):

Your call to `getBundle()` will load a properties file named according to the [strategy described in the javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#getBundle%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.ClassLoader%29). The simplest case would be to simply load it from a file named "abc.properties". What the error is telling you is that whichever properties file is being selected, it doesn't contain a key named "ipAddress". I.e., there should be, but isn't, a line like this in the file:

```
ipAddress=1.2.3.4
```